# 2d array in java for traversing row

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I am trying to traverse a 2 d array row wise with following code.  The issue is it goes to next column instead of next element in the row and when I try putting the column for loop outside, it picks up 2 elements due to the inside row loop. Is there a simpler way of doing this ?

This is my first time posting and i tried searching the solution but didn't found one. Any help will be greatly appreciated. TIA.

```
for (int rowCount = 1; rowCount < data.length; rowCount++) {


    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < data[rowCount].length; colIndex++) {

        String data_parameter;
        data_parameter = data[rowCount][colIndex];

    }

}
```

.

```
LoginID Password    Data1   Data2
login1  mercury test 1  1234
login2  mercury test2   1234
```

Comment: "The issue is it goes to next column instead of next element in the row" - isn't "the next column" == "the next element in the row"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by switching them it should work

```
for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < data!=null ? data[0].length : -1 ; colIndex++) {
    for (int rowCount = 1; rowCount < data.length; rowCount++) {
        String data_parameter = data[rowCount][colIndex];
    }
}
```

---

## EDIT :

r->row & c->column

Elements:

r1c1 r1c2 r1c3
r2c1 r2c2 r2c3
r3c1 r3c2 r3c3

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [][] val = {{"r1c1", "r1c2", "r1c3"},
            {"r2c1", "r2c2", "r2c3"},
            {"r3c1", "r3c2", "r3c3"}};
    for(int row =0;row <val.length; row++){
        for(int col =0;col <val[0].length; col++){
            System.out.print(val[row][col]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("**NEXT**");
    for(int col =0;col <val[0].length; col++){
        for(int row =0;row <val.length; row++){
            System.out.print(val[row][col]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
r1c1 r1c2 r1c3 
r2c1 r2c2 r2c3 
r3c1 r3c2 r3c3 
**NEXT**
r1c1 r2c1 r3c1 
r1c2 r2c2 r3c2 
r1c3 r2c3 r3c3
```

Choose what do you want !!! :p ;)

Comment: That code doesn't compile. You access rowCount before you declare it

Comment: Should have caught that fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. I tried the solution but I get multiple syntax errors one at expression "null :" and other at -1. Pardon my ignorance but I am trying to understand what does the : operator stands for in Java. I am aware about the ?: but not the : alone.

Comment: @sac I did fix it. It was an error on my part ! Dyslexic me !

Comment: I would like to be that kind of Dyslexic :). Thanks the code worked but it still goes from one row to another. May be I confused in my original question. I want it to traverse 1,0 then 2,0, 3,0 i.e from start of single row till the end but  right now it is 0,0 then 1,0. I am new to Java and its bit confusing. Really appreciate all the replies.